# English/ Arabic text direction Support React-Native

Tags: css, react-native

So I have two variables that I receive from the back-end like this:

```
  return (
                    <View key={i} style={styles.subCont}>
                        <Text style={[
                            styles.devicesInfoText,
                            styles.deviceNameText,
                        ]}>
                            {`${x.name}* ${x.quantity}`}
                        </Text>
                        <Text style={styles.devicesInfoText}>{x.price} {constants.strings.sar}</Text>
                    </View>
                    )
```

There's no guarantee if the name would be arabic or English, but my app is rtl so I want the quantity to be always on the left no matter the name is.

These are the stylings I am using:

```
devicesInfoText: {
    fontFamily: constants.fontFamily.bold,
    fontSize: RFValue(14),
    color: constants.colors.black,
},
deviceNameText: {
    flexShrink: 1,
    alignSelf: "center",
    writingDirection: "rtl"
},

subCont: {
    flexDirection: 'row-reverse',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have fixed text places, you could simply have two Text components in one row, for example you could replace:

```
                        <Text style={[
                            styles.devicesInfoText,
                            styles.deviceNameText,
                        ]}>
                            {`${x.name}* ${x.quantity}`}
                        </Text>
```

With this:

```
                        <Text style={[
                            styles.devicesInfoText,
                            styles.deviceNameText,
                        ]}>
                            {`${x.name}* `}
                        </Text>
                        <Text style={[
                            styles.devicesInfoText,
                            styles.deviceNameText,
                        ]}>
                            {`${x.quantity}`}
                        </Text>
```

Comment: That's totally a valid solution, thanks for your answer, but I was wondering if it can be done in one liner instead of repeating the code.